# gtest expect unordered elements are with custom comparator/matcher

Tags: c++, c++11, googletest

I have a list of objects and a list of expected values that the objects can evaluate to after running them through a function.

```
std::vector<Objects> actual;
std::vector<Enum> expected;
bool equals(Object one, Enum two);
```

I want to be able to do something like `UnorderedElementsAre` with a matcher or use `Pointwise` without expecting an order.

I have a couple thoughts for solutions, but I'm looking for other suggestions (especially one's more native to gtest or that make the test easier to read)

1. Sort `actual` then use `Pointwise`
2. Convert all values in `actual` to the corresponding `Enum` value then do `UnorderedElementsAre` on that list and `expected`
3. Write a matcher that hides 1 or 2

Comment: If there's nothing private/protected to compare between `Object` and `Enum`, then you can provide a global `operator ==` for these two classes, then you can use `UnorderedElementsAre` without any matcher.

Comment: BTW `equals` makes a copy of `Object` and `Enum`. Would a const reference make sense?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Good suggestion, if you promote it to an answer I can choose it and close the question.

Comment: @TobiasWollgam Thanks for the suggestion, this was a simplified version of the real code.

Comment: I'm afraid with this code I have no idea how to do it. It depends on what you are comparing (is it a field in `Object`? Have you defined cast operator to `Enum`?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is relatively an old question, anyway I think it's worth to mention that `UnorderedPointwise` [container matcher](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/cheat_sheet.md#container-matchers) is likely what you were looking for.